# R Highcharter: tooltip customization

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I created a chart using highcharter in a shiny dashboard and I am trying to customize the tooltip. The chart is combined line and scatter plot. I would like it to do the following:

1) Have a single box for hover information (it currently has one for the line and one for scatter)

2) Be able to use different column of information that is not used in the series x or y values

I would like the tooltip to display the following information (whether I hover over the scatter point or line) for each particular x-axis value.

**Overall**

Mean: 2 *[Mean: data$avghours]*

Dog: 1 *[data$animal: data$hours]*

Below is the example code I've written that demonstrates my problem:

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (highcharter)


header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example")

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    box(title = "example", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
        highchartOutput("chart")
    )
   )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  date <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  hours <- c(1,5,4,1,6,5,7,5,4,3)
  avghours <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,2)
  animal <- c("dog","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","dog","dog")
  data <- data.frame(date,hours,avghours,animal)

  output$chart <- renderHighchart({

    highchart() %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "Shipments", data=data$hours, type = "scatter", color = "#2670FF", marker = list(radius = 2), alpha = 0.5) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = "Rolling Mean", data=data$avghours, color = "#FF7900") %>%
      hc_yAxis(min = 0, title = list(text = "Hours")) %>%
      hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/54) on Highcharter's GitHub site?

Comment: You can remove the `shiny` tag and all related code with your app. This is a `highcharter` question only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firt of all, you need to add all the data instead give only the vector (the vector DON´T have all the information to the tooltip you want). 
To do this you need change the `data` argument using the `data.frame` with the  `hcaes` helper function in the `mapping` argument to define which variable use in every axis:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = data, mapping = hcaes(x=date, y=hours), name = "Shipments", type = "scatter", color = "#2670FF", marker = list(radius = 2), alpha = 0.5) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = data, hcaes(date, avghours), name = "Rolling Mean", type = "line", color = "#FF7900") %>%
  hc_yAxis(min = 0, title = list(text = "Hours")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE)
```

[image]

Then you can use the `tooltip` argument in every `hc_add_series` to define the tooltip in each series:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = data, hcaes(date, hours), name = "Shipments", type = "scatter",
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "tooltip with 2 values {point.animal}: {point.hours}")) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = data, hcaes(date, avghours), name = "Rolling Mean", type = "line",
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "Avg hour text! {point.avghours}")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(min = 0, title = list(text = "Hours")) %>%
  hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jbkunst ! This is very helpful. Is there a way to get both series on the same tooltip? So when I hover over, I get both `Shipments` and `Rolling Mean` in the same box?

Comment: I don´t know yet. I will look into it